# How can I optimize this function to make an arbitrary number of divs to be of equal height?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if you could help me cut down on the number of total operations in the following function.

```
function equi_hghts (S)
{
/* S: Array of strings which are selectors of elements which are to be given the same height */
   var n = S.length;
   var ES = []; /* Elements selected by S */
   for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      ES.push($(S[i]));
   var maxHeight = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i)
   {
       var thisHeight = ES[i].height;
       if (thisHeight > maxHeight)
           maxHeight = thisHeight;
   }
   for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i)
   {
       ES[i].height(maxHeight);
   }
}
```

For instance, I know that the chunk

```
   for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i)
   {
       ES[i].height(maxHeight);
   }
```

will have 1 useless operation because one div will be getting set to the height which it is already at. I'm also looking for a way to cut down on the number of for loops.

And there's another thing that would help: After the following chunk

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i)
   ES.push($(S[i]));
```

I would like to delete the memory allocated for `S`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
var maxHeight = S.map($)
    .reduce(function(prev,curr){
        return Math.max(prev,curr.height());
    },0);
$(S.join(",")).height(maxHeight);
```

or

```
var q=$(S.join(","));
q.height(
    q.toArray().reduce(function(prev,curr){
        return Math.max(prev,curr.height());
    },0));
```

Comment: I like this approach. Passing the jQuery function to map is brilliant, as is the joining of the array at the end. However, this would cause 2 DOM lookups per element. I would say this is optimized for readability, but you could do better for performance to make it work with a single lookup per element.